# How can I make my Droid2 push Facebook-originated contacts to Google?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, sync, facebook, motorola-droid-2

On my Droid2 (Android Version 2.2) (System Version.2.3.20.A955.Verizon.en.US), I fully utilize the phone's ability to log into a Google, Facebook, and Twitter account, and link the contacts together. Often it [chooses the wrong name to display](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4513/how-can-i-fix-droid2-link-contacts-so-it-chooses-the-right-primary-name), but that is another question entirely. I have already set the option in ...

```
(Contacts) -> [Menu] -> "More (+)" -> "Settings"
```

... to automatically push any newly created contacts to my Google account. If I create a new contact traditionally, via ...

```
(Contacts) -> [Menu] -> "Add contact"
```

... then it works exactly as expected, creating a new contact in both my Phone Contacts and Google Contacts. However, sometimes there are people I know whom I have no contact information for until I friend them on Facebook. At this point, the only contact I have for them is my Facebook contact. I don't like having to rely on only a Facebook contact, and I always take this opportunity to start a Google Contact for them, duplicating what Facebook has already told me. This is where the unexpected behavior begins.

If I select a contact from my phone which is purely a Facebook contact, and click ...

```
... [Menu] -> "Edit"
```

... it brings me to the traditional contact editing screen, presenting me with all of their Facebook information as immutable fields, allowing me to manually duplicate this data into what I would expect would be both a Phone Contact and a Google Contact.

But it's not!!! After manually re-typing in, say, their birthday, e-mail address, and cellphone number (information traditionally available via Facebook), and I click ...

```
"Save"
```

... the resulting contact reads as ...

```
Linked profiles (2)

Facebook: John D.
Phone Contacts: John Doe
```

... with a Google contact nowhere to be seen!! Even if I initiate a manual resynchronization via ...

```
(Home Screen) -> [Menu] -> "Settings" ->  "Accounts" -> "[my Google account]" -> [Menu] -> "Sync now"
```

... the information is still not pushed to my Google Contacts!!

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So far, my only work-around is to recognize a new Facebook contact, navigate away from it, manually create a new completely empty contact by the same name, link the two, then begin duplicating the data. This is cumbersome and should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around is to [use yahoo mail to export your Facebook friends](http://lifehacker.com/5690378/how-to-export-your-friends-email-addresses-from-facebook) then import them into gmail.  It's not a very sustainable workaround for keeping things in sync, but would make the initial sync much easier than manually duplicating the contacts.